# http Get request getting System.CalloutException: Read Time out error

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, webservices, httprequest

I want to get the data from third party app. When i try to get the data through HTTP get request getting System.CalloutException: Read Time out error.

I have checked the endpoint url on browser and can see the data.

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('http://rt4.marcura.com/REST/1.0/search/ticket/?user=salesforce&pass=salesforcepass&query=CX::Team1&format=s&fields=Subject,Queue,CF.{Account%20Name}');
request.setMethod('GET');
request.setTimeout(12000);
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
// If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
    // Deserialize the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
    Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
    // Cast the values in the 'tickets' key as a list
    List<Object> tickets = (List<Object>) results.get('tickets');
    System.debug('Received the following tickets:');
    for (Object ticket: tickets) {
        System.debug(ticket);
    }
}
```

Kindly advise.

Comment: Did you try increasing the time out value in setTimeout method at line 5?

Comment: yes, It's a maximum 120 sec buy still the same error.

Comment: The read time out error is stating that the method did not return an HTTPResponse within the timeout interval. Can you debug the web service to see if the message was received? How long it took?
 
You can configure the timeout too.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm

Comment: Have you tried to access that endpoint with postman or any other client?

Comment: Yes, I have tried endpoint with ARC goggle chrome extension and it's working fine. I tried to debug the code and getting status error 504  bad getaway.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved. It was network issue and solved by white list the Salesforce IP addresses range.